# SonarLint for Eclipse - upcoming version 2 scheduled date and compatibility

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarqube-4.0

is there any planned date for SonarLint 2.0 release?

And will it be compatible with SonarQube 4.5.5?

We started using SonarQube 4.5.5 a few months ago. We couldn't adopt the latest SonarQube release, because we couldn't use the latest Eclipse plug-in. We're still using an old Eclipse version.

However, we're planning on adopting the latest Eclipse version on February/March 2016 and I believe we need to use the SonarLint plug-in.

I was told that the old SonarQube Eclipse plug-in is no longer compatible with the latest Eclipse version.

Is this correct?

Thanks.

Regards,
Nuno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no precise ETA for SonarLint 2.0 yet. We are making sure that the 1.x series are working perfectly before moving on this next version that will bring the connected mode.

I don't know who told you that the SonarQube Eclipse is no longer compatible with latest Eclipse version, you should check things by yourself on the [documentation page](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+SonarQube+in+Eclipse) before asking the question: it is pretty clear  that the plugin is perfectly compatible with Eclipse Mars and SQ 4.5 LTS.